# Which JetBrains IDE is more suitable for nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm currently using **IntelliJ IDEA**, but I'm thinking of moving to **WebStorm**.

Per your experience, which would be more suitable for nodejs development?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, **WebStorm** is the most suitable editor for development with Node.js. Personally, however, I don't find use of most of WebStorm's features. What I look for in an editor is simplicity, minimal interface and quick opening of files. Having said that **IntelliJ IDEA** would work fine with Node.js as well. Since it is just javascript.

Currently I am using [brackets](http://brackets.io/) and [text adept](http://foicica.com/textadept/) interchangably. Both of them are free and you should give them a try.

**Edit**

For intellisense support in node js there are following options:

- Ecllipse with Node.js [plugin](http://www.nodeclipse.org/)
- Web Matrix
- WebStorm

Comment: What about IntelliSense feature? I'm new to node.js, so it would be very helpful to use it.

Comment: There is some intellisense brackets.Node js and javascript feature set is small.I don't think that you need intellisense all that much as compared to languages such as java.Also if you really want intellisense give [webmatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) a try.Take a look at the options that I have mentioned and get a feel of programming with these editors before purchasing web storm.Use the one you like the best.

Comment: Intellisense would be more critical for me when I'll start working with Express, Angular, CompoundJS etc...

Comment: I come from programming in visual studio environment.So I was just like you when I was starting out with node js.I thought I needed intellisense. After a few days of spending time with node js I found that I don't need it at all.Javascript does not have a ton of methods.Even node js api can be all accommodated on a single page. So I traded intellisense for ease of use which these editors provided.Spend some time working with different editors and node js.It  will pay in the long run.

Comment: What about debugging nodejs applications? doing that with intelliJ IDEA is certainly not a treat.